# Controls alignment in WPF

Tags: wpf, panel

I have designed a window in WPF with an image in left and two buttons immediately next to the image.
And i set the `WindowState` to `Maximized`.

But while running the application, the gap b/w controls got increased. I want the alignment as it is in the design time. In `windows application` its getting as it is, where as in `wpf` the controls are automatically get aligned.

Please hepl me to do this, im new to wpf. Can `Panels` resolve this issue?

**Samplle**

```
<Window x:Class="AnalogCalibrationTool.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Analog Hardware Calibration Tool" 
    Height="500" 
    Width="700" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
    WindowState="Maximized" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
<Grid>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84.436,164.428,0,147.763" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" />
    <Button Height="23" Margin="326.634,0,276.639,147.763" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Button</Button>
    <Button Height="29.997" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,184.426,144.264" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75">Button</Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Provide a sample of your XAML

Comment: You should add your image and buttons in specific rows and columns. Look at http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Name="image1" Width="200" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Aqua"  />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Name="button1" Height="23" Width="60" Content="Button1"/>
        <Button Name="button2" Height="23" Width="60" Content="Button2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the sample a rectangle is used as a fake for your image.